# Is there any way in which i can goto a directory found out using "find" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, directory

I would like to use a command that change the current working directory to the one i find out using the "find" command.Is there any way that I can do that on a single line in bash?
I would like to use a command that change the current working directory to the one i find out using the `find` command.Is there any way that I can do that on a single line in bash?
I want to go to a directory called "mydir".I only know that it is somewhere in "documents". I want to change my current working directory to "mydir".
I know that I can know the path using  `find -name mydir`.

Comment: On a single line? Why? And what have you tried?

Comment: So, I don't have to know all the parent directories of the directory I wish to go.Then it's so easy to switch between my favorite directories .

Comment: Consider setting `CDPATH`... https://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/cdpath/

Answer (score 3):

this should do..

```
$ cd "$(find . -type d -name myDir -print -quit)"
```

`-quit` to ensure at most one value is returned (and finish looking after first match), may not be supported in all `find`s.  Otherwise you need to filter the result but will take longer.

Comment: Might be useful to point out that OP could make an `alias` or `function` of this in his shell profile to save typing it.